# how to display items for detected beacons only once when iPhone is in region using swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, beacon

I’m using swift3 to build an iOS and WatchOS app, which detects the nearby Estimote beacons and display on the screen a table of Items linked to different beacons. And once the phone is out of the beacon’s region, the items which are linked to that beacon disappear from the screen. I also want each item to be displayed only ONCE and NOT periodically when the device enters a beacon region.

So, what I did is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {  var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
} //end didload

  /////////////////////////BEACON CODES////////////////////////

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                startScanning()
            }
        }
    }
}//end location manager  

func startScanning() { let uuid = UUID(uuidString:"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")  // I used the default UUID for all of the 3 beacons
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid! , identifier: "MyBeacons")
     locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
     locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}//end startscanning

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
 //to remove beacons with unknown
 let known = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown}
  if (known.count > 0){
        let uiRealm = try! Realm()
        var Beacons = uiRealm.objects(Beacon.self)
        var major = 0

       for beacon in beacons{
            for b in Beacons { //the beacon id in the DB is its major # and NOT the UUID
                major = (Int)(b.beaconID)!
               if major == (Int)(beacon.major) { //retrieve all items linked to this beacon, it could be one or many 
                    var items = uiRealm.objects(Item.self).filter("beacon.beaconID == '\(major)'")
                    print("items for beacon id = \(major) are :")
                    //print items
                    for i in items{
                        print (i.name)
                    } //end i
                }//end if major == beacon.major
            } //end b loop
        } //end beacon loop
     } //end if
    } //location manager method
}
```

**THE OUTPUT:**

```
items for beacon id = 50038 are :
Ibraheem, Asma

items for beacon id = 51802 are :
Shoug

items for beacon id = 28612 are :
Mona

items for beacon id = 50038 are :
Ibraheem, Asma

items for beacon id = 51802 are :
Shoug

items for beacon id = 28612 are :
Mona

items for beacon id = 51802 are :
Shoug

items for beacon id = 28612 are :
Mona

items for beacon id = 50038 are :
Ibraheem, Asma

items for beacon id = 28612 are :
Mona

items for beacon id = 50038 are :
Ibraheem, Asma
```

The items are printed each second (infinite loop), but what I want is to print each item ONLY ONCE (for example: Mona should be printed only once) whenever the phone enters the region. 
Also, with this code, the item disappears whenever the phone is out of region (which is what I want).

Comment: Store the once already shown and do not show them again.

Comment: In "theory", the way to determine a unique ID, is by checking UUID, major AND minor. If they are the same, exclude of one already in the list, exclude it.